# Fibrations of the injective model structure on G-simplicial sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Consider the category of $G$-simplicial sets endowed with the injective model structure, i.e. cofibrations are the injective maps and weak equivalences are the maps which are equivalences when seen as maps of simplicial sets.

My question is: *what are the fibrations of this model category ?* (aside from "the maps satisfying the right lifting property...")

This question of what are the fibrations of the injective model structure have already been asked several time on this forum and elsewhere, but it apparently never receive an answer in the more general case. I think this specific case is easier.

Indeed, I've been able to check that the trivial fibrations are exactly the maps $f$ such that for each subgroup $H \subset G$ the map $f$ restricted to a map between $H$-invariants is a trivial kan fibration.

It is hence natural to think that fibrations might be defined by the same property: for each $H$ the restriction of $f$ as a map between the $H$-invariants is a kan fibration.

It is indeed true that fibrations do satisfy this property, but as pointed out by Charles Rezk in the comments, this is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Wouldn't your description imply that the projective and injective model structures coincide?

Comment: There's a model structure on $G$-simplicial sets, where the cofibrations and fibrations are as you suggest, but the weak equivalences are *equivariant* ones (i.e., weak equivalence on $H$-invariants for all $H$).  The fibrations in your injective structure will be characterized by more restrictive property.

Comment: Matthias Wendt: No for the projective model structure the fibration and trivial fibration are defined by forgeting the G action, and the cofibration are inclusions $A \subset B$ where the elements of $B$ which are not in $A$ have a stabilizer reduced to $\{0\}$.

Charles Rezk: thanks for that remark, this is really helpful ! (If someone can point a reference for this it might also be helpful)

Comment: @SimonHenry The model structure is the "usual" equivariant model structure.  There are surely many references: maybe Dwyer & Kan, "Singular functors and realization functors". https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/SingularAndRealization.pdf

Comment: The mixed model structure, whose fibrations and acyclic fibrations are as described in the main post, is explored by Shipley, see Proposition 1.3 in “A convenient model category for commutative ring spectra”.

Comment: @SimonHenry: do you have a reference for the characterization of the cofibrations you mentioned in the projective model structure ? Thanks.

Comment: @Asymptotik: No. I computed that my self. Roughly, Its easy to check that the generating cofib satisfies these properties and that they are stable under retract,pushout and transfinite composition, and then you have to check that maps with these property satisfy the LLP with respect to trivial kan fibration and this can be donne by construction the diagonal filing on $n$-simplicies by induction on $n$. With those two thing in hand, the small object argument conclude the proof.

Comment: @SimonHenry: thanks for your answer, your construction of the diagonal filler is "pointwise" as I understand, so it's not clear for me that at the end you get a natural transformation compatible with the G-action.

Comment: Oh indeed you're right: I forgot half of the argument. you also need to use the assumption that the stabilizer of each points not in $A$ is trivial, then you chose a lifting of one point in each orbit and you extend to the rest of the orbit in the unique way that respect the $G$-action.